# The difference between a directive and an element name

Tags: html, angular

I encountered this first while using Angular/Material, but I think this is a general HTML question.   I have not had any luck finding a reference that would explain it.

What is the underlying functional difference between

```
    <mat-table [dataSource]="data">
    ...
    </mat-table>
```

as opposed to

```
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="data">
    ...
    </table>
```

They both seem to work the same.   At least I haven't found any difference other than how CSS element references are coded.   But what is the background as to why these alternate encodings exist in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the source code:
https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/table/table.ts#L20

In the `MatTable` decorator there is:
`selector: 'mat-table, table[mat-table]'`

Angular directive supports multiple selectors. According to the [official documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#selector) - selector can be declared as one of the following:

- `element-name`: Select by element name.
- `.class`: Select by class name.
- ...
- `selector1, selector2`: Select if either selector1 or selector2 matches.

So there is no difference in terms of functionality, since the MatTable Component just has two different selectors.